# Build Samba 4.5.3 from source on Ububtu 16.04(Use Sourcery G++)

Tags: build, samba

First, install Sourcery G++:

```
./arm-2009q1*************************.bin
```

Second,add path to Sourcery G++:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path_to_Sourcery G++/bin
```

Everything is fine. After that I go to the directory and execute the script:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
export CPP=${CROSS_COMPILE}cpp
export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
export LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld
export AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar
export RANLIB=${CROSS_COMPILE}ranlib

./configure --without-ldap --without-ads --disable-cups --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix= --with-configdir=/etc  samba_cv_CC_NEGATIVE_ENUM_VALUES=yes libreplace_cv_HAVE_GETADDRINFO=no ac_cv_file__proc_sys_kernel_core_pattern=yes
```

Result:

```
....
     Checking uname sysname type              : Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "./buildtools/bin/waf", line 76, in <module>
            Scripting.prepare(t, cwd, VERSION, wafdir)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 145, in prepare
            prepare_impl(t, cwd, ver, wafdir)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 135, in prepare_impl
            main()
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/wscript", line 378, in main
            wildcard_main(wildcard_cmd)
          File "./buildtools/wafsamba/samba_wildcard.py", line 110, in wildcard_main
            fun(ctx)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 241, in configure
            conf.sub_config([''])
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Configure.py", line 237, in sub_config
            self.recurse(k, name='configure')
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 656, in recurse
            f(self)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/wscript", line 109, in configure
            conf.RECURSE('lib/replace')
          File "./buildtools/wafsamba/samba_utils.py", line 452, in RECURSE
            return ctx.sub_config(relpath)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Configure.py", line 237, in sub_config
            self.recurse(k, name='configure')
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 656, in recurse
            f(self)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 743, in wrap
            ret = fun(k)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/lib/replace/wscript", line 28, in configure
            conf.RECURSE('buildtools/wafsamba')
          File "./buildtools/wafsamba/samba_utils.py", line 452, in RECURSE
            return ctx.sub_config(relpath)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Configure.py", line 237, in sub_config
            self.recurse(k, name='configure')
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 656, in recurse
            f(self)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 743, in wrap
            ret = fun(k)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/lib/replace/../../buildtools/wafsamba/wscript", line 320, in configure
            conf.CHECK_UNAME()
          File "./buildtools/wafsamba/samba_conftests.py", line 452, in CHECK_UNAME
            msg="Checking uname %s type" % v):
          File "./buildtools/wafsamba/samba_autoconf.py", line 436, in CHECK_CODE
            define_ret=define_ret)
          File "./buildtools/wafsamba/samba_conftests.py", line 52, in check
            ret = self.run_c_code(*k, **kw)
          File "/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.7.1/third_party/waf/wafadmin/Tools/config_c.py", line 575, in run_c_code
            proc = Utils.pproc.Popen([lastprog] + args, stdout=Utils.pproc.PIPE, stderr=Utils.pproc.PIPE)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
            errread, errwrite)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
            raise child_exception
        OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I can not understand the error. There are many similar errors in google, but they do not help me. Tell me how to deal with this error.
P.S. add shell=True  = work! New problem:

```
Checking for program gcc or cc           : arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for program git                 : /usr/bin/git 
Check for -MD                            : yes 
Checking for program gdb                 : /usr/bin/gdb 
Checking build system                    : Linux ivanPC 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
Checking for header sys/utsname.h        : yes 
Checking uname sysname type              : not found 
Checking uname machine type              : not found 
Checking uname release type              : not found 
Checking uname version type              : not found 
Checking for header stdio.h              : yes 
Checking simple C program                : /home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.5.3/lib/replace/../../buildtools/wafsamba/wscript:316: error: the configuration failed (see '/home/ivan/samba/samba/samba-4.5.3/bin/config.log')
```